# Woocommerce changing postalcode to dropdown menu

Tags: javascript, php, woocommerce

I am try to change postalcode in checkout page and limit it to specific options so i used this code

```
// Hook in
add_filter('woocommerce_default_address_fields','custom_override_default_address_fields');
```

// Our hooked in function - $fields is passed via the filter!
function custom_override_default_address_fields($address_fields) {

```
// Just changing what is needed to turn it into a select.
// Modify other options if you need.
$address_fields['postcode']['type'] = 'select';
$address_fields['postcode']['options'] = array('12652' => "Area 1",
                                               '21511' => "Area 2",
                                               '42511' => "Area 3");
```

$address_fields['postcode']['default'] =12652;

`return $address_fields;`

Actually everything is okay but the main issue is that option's values i used it to calculate the shipping cost but nothing updated .. i'm looking for the js stuff to get the selector of postalcode but i can't find or solve this issue .. any help?

Comment: Please, read [how to ask useful questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and try to improve yours. Also, try to improve formatting on the code.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what i did and it worked fine with me.

**Step 1:** Add this filter in order to add new field in checkout form.

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_checkout_fields' , 'add_address_type_field' );
function add_address_type_field( $fields ) {

    $address_type_field = array(
        'type'      => 'select',
        'required'  => false,
        'class'     => array('address-field', 'form-row-wide', 'validate-addresstype'),
        'clear'     => true,
        'options'   => array(
            'postCode' => 'Area 1',
            'postCode' => 'Area 2',
        ),
    );
    
    $fields['billing']['billing_address_type']   = $address_type_field;
    return $fields;
}
```

**Step 2:** Using css to hide default postal code input

```
#billing_postcode{
    display:none;   
}
```

**Step 3:** Using JavaScript Events to make eventlistener 'Change' .. once the select value change event assign this value to default post code input by adding this code in form-billing.php

```
document.querySelector('#billing_address_type').addEventListener("change", function(){
    document.querySelector('input#billing_postcode').value = document.querySelector('#billing_address_type').value;
    jQuery('body').trigger('update_checkout');
});
```

Comment: You may also set drop-down value to the billing field value outside the change event, just in case user reload the browser